# Socket Connection between django servers

Tags: python, django, sockets

I am newbie for django and python. The thing what I need is, connecting **more than one django server with socket**. One of these servers (main server) will get a request from mobile client with Django-REST API, and then, it should transmit it to the other django servers related to an ID of the server. (e.g. When main server gets data with an ID as 1, it should transmit the data to the server#1, if it gets the data with ID 2, it should transmit the data to server#2)
I am looking forward your advices..

**p.s.** Http requests cannot be sent to the django servers except main one. Each of them are intranet application and locations are different. The only way to send data to these servers via http is, sending the request to main server with the ID of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to send an (internal) http request not even to localhost you can try to speak to the WSGI API of the different django apps. The main app might create a WSGI application object and fill it with pseudo request data.

```
# views.py of the main server

def myview(self, request):
    # do some stuff
    if server_id = 1:
        from server_1_app.wsgi import application
        response = application(environ, pseudo_request)
    # ...
```